# Restriction and dependence in the Dirichlet distributon

Tags: dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-regression

**The Dirichlet distribution** is sometimes said that it is **"too restrictive and imposes strong conditions on the dependence between components"**. What is the reason?

Comment: what restrictions and conditions does the dirichlet impose

Comment: @develarist
For example, the correlation structure of a Dirichlet composition is negative: if x has a Dirichlet distribution, corr(x_i, x_j) < 0 for every i neq j. Is it true?